# Bootstrap 3 - 3x btn-group with dropdown animate open all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I need to create 3x image with dropdown menu. I chosen btn-group with dropdown, but when I add slide transition (JS), there is a  problem.
When I click on one - all is open, but I want to open only this one, how do this?
My code:

```
                   <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">First action</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.btn-group -->
                    <div class="clearfix"></div><!-- /.clearfix -->
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Second action</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.btn-group -->
                    <div class="clearfix"></div><!-- /.clearfix -->
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Third action</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.btn-group -->
```

And JS:

```
    $('.btn-group').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown();
    });

    $('.btn-group').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `.dropdown-menu`:

```
$('.btn-group').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown();
});
$('.btn-group').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```